# BigQuery left outer join without duplicating keys but keeping unique values from table to the right

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Sorry if the title is confusing. I don't know how to correctly articulate this question because it's quite complicated for me. I have 2 tables. Simplified example:

admin

| id | timestamp | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202303161000 | 2023-03-16 | test account |
| 2 | 202303161000 | 2023-03-16 | spam |

ua

| dateHourMinute | defaultChannelGrouping |
| --- | --- |
| 202303161000 | organic search |
| 202303161000 | direct |

I need to join these two tables, keeping all rows in tha `admin` table and only the matching rows in `ua` table. The problem is that the matching colums `timestamp` and `dateHourMinute` are not unique (several users may register at the same minute).
So far I've come up with this

```sql
MERGE `my_dataset.connector` t
USING (
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(timestamp) as timestamp,
    MAX(date) as date,
    MAX(status) as status,
    MAX(dateHourMinute) as dateHourMinute,
    MAX(defaultChannelGrouping) as defaultChannelGrouping

FROM `my_dataset.admin` AS admin
LEFT OUTER JOIN `my_dataset.ua` AS ua
ON admin.timestamp = ua.dateHourMinute
GROUP BY id
) s
ON t.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
    id = s.id,
    timestamp = s.timestamp,
    date = s.date,
    status = s.status,
    dateHourMinute = s.dateHourMinute,
    defaultChannelGrouping = s.defaultChannelGrouping
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT(
    id,
    timestamp,
    date,
    status,
    dateHourMinute,
    defaultChannelGrouping
    )
VALUES(
    s.id,
    s.timestamp,
    s.date,
    s.status,
    s.dateHourMinute,
    s.defaultChannelGrouping
)
```

The `connector` table produced by this query looks like this

| id | timestamp | date | status | dateHourMinute | defaultChannelGrouping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 202303161000 | 2023-03-16 | spam | 202303161000 | organic search |
| 1 | 202303161000 | 2023-03-16 | test account | 202303161000 | organic search |

As you see `defualtChannelGrouping` is the same for both users. I would like to get the following result

| id | timestamp | date | status | dateHourMinute | defaultChannelGrouping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 202303161000 | 2023-03-16 | spam | 202303161000 | organic search |
| 1 | 202303161000 | 2023-03-16 | test account | 202303161000 | direct |

I know that it is flawed in this way that I don't know whether `defaultChannelGrouping` was correctly assigned to user `id` but to be honest I don't need to know this. I only need to know that one user came from `organic search` and other from `direct`.
Can anybody help with this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a 1-1 relationship and you just want to randomly assign one when there are duplicate join keys, you could assign a ROW_NUMBER() and join on that as well. Something like this:

```
WITH rn_admin AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp) as rn
  FROM admin
),
rn_ua AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp) as rn
  FROM ua
)
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM rn_admin
JOIN rn_ua
USING(timestamp, rn)
```